# how to recursively build treeview in c#

Tags: c#, recursion, treeview

```
private void enumerateValues(IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>> iEnumerator, TreeNode parentnode)
{
   if(iEnumerator is IEnumerable)
   {
     // ADD THE KEY
     TreeNode childNode = parentnode.Nodes.Add(iEnumerator.Current.Key);

     enumerateValues(iEnumerator.Current.Value, childNode);
   }
  else
   {
     /// add the value
     TreeNode childNode = parentnode.Nodes.Add(iEnumerator.Current.Value.ToString());
   }
}
```

I somehow get the following error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.enumerateValues(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>>,
>    System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode)' has some invalid arguments
>   Argument '1': cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>>'

How can i fix it please

Comment: iEnumerator will always be IEnumerable... you may wanted to check iEnumerator.Current.Value in your if clause

Answer (score 1):

The following line is most likely the culprit:

```
enumerateValues(iEnumerator.Current.Value, childNode);
```

Because the `enumerateValues` method accepts a `IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`, the values of the key-value pairs will always be of type `object`. Therefore you cannot call the method with `iEnumerator.Current.Value`, because the value isn't of type `IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`.

This is exactly what the error message tells you:

> Argument '1': cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>>'

You will have to cast `iEnumerator.Current.Value` to the correct type first, before you can call the method. You can do this using the [**as** operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28VS.71%29.aspx).

```
private void enumerateValues(IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>> iEnumerator, TreeNode parentnode)
{
  // Loop through the values.
  while (iEnumerator.MoveNext())
  {
    // Try a 'safe' cast of the current value.
    // If the cast fails, childEnumerator will be null.
    var childEnumerator = iEnumerator.Current.Value as IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>>;

    if (childEnumerator != null)
    {
      TreeNode childNode = parentnode.Nodes.Add(iEnumerator.Current.Key);

      enumerateValues(childEnumerator, childNode);
    }
    else
    {
      TreeNode childNode = parentnode.Nodes.Add(iEnumerator.Current.Value.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

I also suggest you use [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) instead of `IEnumerator<T>`, if you can. It shows the intent of the code more clearly, you won't have to handle the iteration manually and you can use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx) on it.

```
private void enumerateValues(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> items, TreeNode parentnode)
{
  foreach (var item in items)
  {
    // Try a 'safe' cast of the current value.
    // If the cast fails, childEnumerator will be null.
    var childEnumerator = item.Value as IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>;

    if (childEnumerator != null)
    {
      TreeNode childNode = parentnode.Nodes.Add(item.Key);

      enumerateValues(childEnumerator, childNode);
    }
    else
    {
      TreeNode childNode = parentnode.Nodes.Add(item.Value.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```